# arning: Can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component

Tags: react-native

I have a warning when I rotate between screens, I tried to solve the problem but unsuccessfully. This usually does not happen for the first time but other times.
I know it has to do with a certain time but if anyone can help me I will be happy.
I searched for an answer here but did not find anything similar to my code

```
state = { email: '', password: '', error: '', loading: false };

constructor(props)
{
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    loggedin: false
};
//this.registerUser('ttt@gmail.com', 'fffhhhhff');
var that = this;    
f.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if(user){
    //Logged in
    that.setState({
      loggedin: true
    });
    console.log('Logged in', user);
  }
  else{
    //Logged out
    that.setState({
      loggedin: false
    });
    console.log('Logged out');
  }
});
}

loginUser = async(email, pass) => {

if(email != '' && pass != ''){
  //
  try{
    let user = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    console.log(user);
  } catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
}
else{

  //if they are empty
  alert('Missing email or password')
}
}

registerUser = (email, password) => {

console.log(email, password);
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then((userObj) => console.log(email, password, userObj))
.catch((error) => console.log('error logging in', error));

}

signUserOut = () => {
auth.signOut()
.then(() => {
  console.log('Logged out...');
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error', error);
});
}
```

render() {

```
return (
  <View>
    { this.state.loggedin == true ? (
      <View>
        <CardSection>
          <Button
            onPress = { () => this.signUserOut() }>
            Log Out
          </Button>
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          <Text>Logged in....</Text>
        </CardSection>
      </View>
    ) : (
      <View>
        { this.state.emailloginView == true ? (
         <Card>
          <CardSection >
            <Input
              placeholder="user@gmail.com"
              lable="Email"
              value = {this.state.email}
              onChangeText = {email => this.setState({ email })}
            />
          </CardSection>
          <CardSection>
            <Input
              secureTextEntry
              placeholder="password"
              lable="Password"
              value = {this.state.password}
              onChangeText = {password => this.setState({ password })}
            />
          </CardSection>
          <CardSection>
            <Button
              onPress = { () => this.loginUser(this.state.email , this.state.password) }>
              Login
            </Button>
          </CardSection>
        </Card>
        ): (
          <View>

          </View>
        )}
        { this.state.emailloginView != true ? (
        <CardSection>
          <Button
            onPress = { () => this.setState({emailloginView: true})}>
            Login With Email
          </Button>
        </CardSection>
        ) : (
          <View>

          </View>
        )} 
      </View>
    )}
  </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happened when you call `setState`, but your components are unmounted. For example here `f.auth().onAuthStateChanged(callback)` you might receive the callback, when you are not in this screen anymore. 
To solve the problem in a clean way, you can use hooks like this:

```js
   const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
   useEffect(() => {
      let isMounted = true;
      f.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if(!isMounted){
          return;
        }
        if (user) {
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        } else {
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
        }
      });
      return ()=>{
        isMounted = false;
      }
    }, []);
```

By the way, a better solution is to cancel the request when you leave the page.